# Debug C++ app with sudo in Netbeans

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sudo, netbeans-8

I have been trying to debug a c++ app that need sudo to run via netbeans but with no success yet.I use an ubuntu 16.04 VM with Ntebeans 8.2 and gdb 7.12. Firstly I used the common solutions I found by googling:
1) Use the script solution with

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo /usr/bin/gdb $*
```

script loaded in debug command under tools->c++->debug command
2) I updated the gdp into 7.12.
However every time I get the following pop up message : 
**gdb has unexpectedly stopped with return 1**
Afterwards I contacted the Netbeans forum and I got the following two alternatives:
1) setcap on you executable so you don't need to be root.
2) Create a "remote location" root@localhost and set it for your project configuration.
So firstly I tried the command

> setcap cap_net_raw+ep /myapp

at the distributable c++ file that was created by Netbeans when Debug mode was used. When I run the app I had no problem but when I tried to debug I again got the above pop up message.
Lastly I tried to build a new host under my project with the name root@localhost but I always get
**Unable to establish connection with root@localhost on port 22.**
On the other hand the configuration of ssh_d is correct in ubuntu since the connection via shh root@localhost is always succesfull and I also gave sudo ufw allow 22 to allow port 22 to listen to ssh.
Has any encountered a similar problem? Any ideas on how to solve it or just use another IDE?

Comment: why do you use `sudo`? no need to use that

Comment: @k-five the reason that I needed to use sudo was because the app contains use of raw sockets which need sudo access to run or setcap capabilities. How do you mean that I do not need sudo is there another alternative?

Comment: I have no experience with **VM** but with Ubuntu a little. Now I am on Ubuntu 16. First compile your program with **flag** `-g`. And to escape each time enter `sudo` command, at first use `sudo -s` then `gdb bin-fine`

Comment: @k-five Are the above applicable to Netbeans, because by command line I can use the native gdb. However I try to make netbeans work because it debugger is far more convenient for my little ubuntu experience  than the command line one.

Comment: you installed **VM** and then installed **Netbeans** on *VM* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134584/discussion-between-k-five-and-dk13).